# Generate a BPSK modulated signal with non zero mean

Tags: continuous-signals

I want to generate a BPSK modulated signal with non zero mean. I don't know how to add a non zero mean.

Comment: I guess you're referring to the baseband signal before modulation (?)

Answer (score 1):

The signal will have a non-zero mean if there are more ones than zeros, or vice-versa.

In academic exercises we usually assume that the data is random with even probabilities so there will be about the same number of ones as zeros.  In real life we use scramblers to makes sure that the modulated data has about the same number of ones as zeros, regardless of what the payload data is.

At any rate, if there are more "ones" symbols than there are "zeros" symbols (or vice versa), there will be a non-zero mean.

Comment: Huh? A BPSK signal will have nonzero mean if the data is unbalanced? Are you talking of the RF signal or the baseband (meaning antipodal but not _phase-shift-keyed_) signal?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: This was also my comment to the OP's question (see above). I suppose Jim Clay's interpretation is the only interpretation of the question that makes sense. But I agree that the question as it is currently phrased does not make much sense.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am talking about the baseband anti-podal signal.  An unbalanced BPSK signal has non-zero mean, which is why they use scramblers to try to balance it.

Answer (score -1):

You could of course generate a "normal" BPSK signal with equal probability of input bits '1' and '0' and then add a constant offset value after BPSK modulation.